# Is The Truman Show on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/217565/102999) about *The Truman Show*. There are three close votes saying it’s off-topic. **Is *The Truman Show* a work of science fiction or fantasy?**

Comment: The comments there explain it all, it's definitely on-topic. If someone's up to copy-paste them into an answer...

Comment: Three close votes, and a general consensus in comments that it's on-topic? Come back when it actually gets closed :-P

Comment: I'd be interested to see who voted to close it though.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I wanted something to ping the close voters with, so I wrote this.

Comment: @Valorum: Your wish is [my command](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/151850) (although, frankly, I'm not entirely clear on what you plan to do with that information...).

Comment: @Stormblessed You're missing my point, which is that it wasn't really necessary to write a meta post when the discussion had already been had in comments with consensus against the close-voters, and the question was never actually closed. It's just a way to get free meta points ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Meta is the place to get site policies ironed out. It is a place visible to the whole community, rather than just in context of a single question. Comments are for clarification of the question/answer and can be deleted at any time, they aren't meant to be long-term storage for off/on-topic discussions. In fact, given this meta exists the comments there should probably be purged now.

Comment: @Randal'Thor agreeing with Robotnik—people don't seem to care about comments. Valorum's question, posted after there were a lot of comments posted on mine, still got two close votes on it very quickly. As you know, moderators love to delete comments. Meta stays a lot longer.

Comment: @Stormblessed - There also seems to be a hard core of '***Truman = Not sci-fi***' users who're busily downvoting any question about the film and close-voting. Having a Meta consensus means that unsure users can post their Truman Show questions with confidence.

Comment: @Randal'Thor There is no such thing as "free meta points", since meta sites don't grant any reputation.

Comment: @IMSoP Well technically you get "meta points" as in badge progression.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## Yes

Many things make this film on-topic. A few:

- The giant dome built that a whole (fake) city fits in.

  - It is shown that real lighting storms can be created in it.
- It’s pretty dystopian.

  - Truman is effectively owned by the company making the show, and they have gotten away for it for 30 years.
  - Even without tech like the dome, [dystopias are on-topic here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12364/102999).
- According to [Valorum’s answer to my question on Main](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/217567/102999), a magazine is shown out of the dome as having a date of 1999—the movie is from 1998—so it obviously takes place at least a year in the future.
- [Wikipedia describes it as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Truman_Show) a "satirical science fiction film".

Comment: Yeah agreed with most of that except for the last point. "One year into the future" isn't really sci-fi per se. If I write a police investigation novel set in 2671 there will most likely be sci-fi elements, if it's set in 2020, meh. My point being​, a single year gap doesn't seem enough to guarantee SFFness

Comment: @Jen I guess so.

Comment: Wikipedia describes it as a "1998 American satirical science fiction film", so yes it's on topic

Comment: @fez - Fan0edited Wikipedia says whatever you tell it to say. I could just as easily edit it to say that the Truman show is a *"1994 pudding cup with extra sprinkles"*

Comment: @Valorum - fan edited yes, but in my experience an edit like that would get reverted  back pretty quickly. Additionally, IMDB has it as: Comedy, Drama, Sci-Fi. Googling "the truman show genre" shows Science fiction and fantasy among others. So it's not just coming from Wikipedia. Rotten Tomatoes does only describe it as Comedy/Drama though

Comment: @Fez - I've found a much better way is to look to see how the makers describe it and how it was marketed

Comment: @Valorum - fair enough, I agree that trumps any website that could describe it as anything they want

Comment: @Valorum the source is a Popular Mechanics article, so I guess it's correct.

Comment: @Jenayah does a story that takes place in 2671 ,but not use any science fiction elements at all, as if it was in 2019, guarantees SFFness?

Comment: @atayenel probably not. Depends on how it's presented I'd say. Not sure why a writer would set up a story so far in the future, not too have society evolved a tad bit. That'd seem like an odd choice of writing

Comment: @Jenayah - If a story was set hundreds of years into the future, but had an *entirely contemporary (2019) setting*, the fact that it's an anachronistic setting would raise a whole bunch of entirely on-topic questions.

Comment: @Valorum RE: Wikipedia could say that The Truman Show is a pudding cup. We should be careful not to make overly exaggerated claims. While the accuracy of information on Wikipedia is still hotly debated, outright ridiculous claims are caught very quickly. When editing an existing article, that becomes even more hastily rectified. Your argument was probably intended to be "just because it's on Wikipedia doesn't make it true", which was perfectly meritorious on its own without any embellishment.

Comment: @BrianR - It could say that for quite a while though, until someone notices and edits it back again. There are, however, many untrue claims on Wikipedia that have stayed up for years, even in the face of some quite considerable efforts to bring the info down.

Comment: @Stormblessed - Why in particular would you expect a journalist with no connection to the film to have anything more than a relatively informed *opinion* on the subject? You say "Popular Mechanics" as if it's more than a glossy mag with clickbait articles.

Comment: @Valorum well I’m saying that it’s not something one random person just put on the article with no source.

Comment: the intense storm they manufacture in the climax alone could count as sci-fi

Comment: Hi buddy! So, lightning storms _can_ be manufactured. :)